# Entity Framework Metadata LINQ (Converting from C# to VB.NET)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, metadata, entity

I've got a query in C# that is working for me to query the metadata for the Entity Framework.  I need to convert it to VB.NET, but I'm struggling to convert the AS keyword to "cast" meta to System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType.  I've tried TryCast, CType, Cast, etc.

Here's the query in C#:

```
var queryResult = from meta in oc.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace)
                  .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == System.Data.Metadata.Edm.BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
                                  from p in (meta as System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType).Properties
                                  .Where(p => p.DeclaringType.Name == entityClassType.Name
                                  && p.Name == propertyName)
                                  select p;
```

This is the closest I've come to getting it to compile in VB.NET (the As keyword in underlined and says ')' expected:

```
Dim query2 = _
             From meta In entityObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace) _
                  .Where(Function(m) m.BuiltInTypeKind = System.Data.Metadata.Edm.BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType) _
                  From p In (meta As System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType).Properties _
                  .Where(Function(p) p.DeclaringType.Name = entity.GetType().Name _
                         And p.Name = propertyName) _
                  Select p
```

This is killing me.  I'm so close...

Comment: You said you've tried CType. Does @dahlbyk's answer work for you?

Comment: So I completely missed that you said you had tried CType. Try OfType(). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CType to type cast:

```
...
From p In CType(meta, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType).Properties _
...
```

**Update:** Looking again at the query, I would suggest using [OfType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) instead:

```
From meta In entityObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace) _
             .OfType(Of System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType)() _
From p In meta.Properties _
Where p.DeclaringType.Name = entity.GetType().Name _
    And p.Name = propertyName _
Select p
```

**Update 2:** Also, it looks like GetItems() has a [generic version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739030.aspx) that I suspect will return only items of your desired type:

```
From meta In entityObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(Of System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType)(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace) _
From p In meta.Properties _
Where p.DeclaringType.Name = entity.GetType().Name _
    And p.Name = propertyName _
Select p
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were writing this query in VB.NET, I would do it like this without the lambdas. I think it's easier to read, but they way you're doing it would probably be easier for a C# developer to read.

```
Dim query2 = _
    From meta In entityObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace) _
        Where m.BuiltInTypeKind = System.Data.Metadata.Edm.BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType _
            From p In CType(meta, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType).Properties _
                Where p.DeclaringType.Name = entity.GetType().Name _
                     And p.Name = propertyName) _
            Select p
```